# Obtener datos de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy iterando un array de objetos para obtener sus datos, pero me esta mandando error.

Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal.

Les comparto el array de objetos que intento iterar

> Código para iterar array de objetos.

```
if (!$.isEmptyObject(estatus)) {

        var arr_data = [];
        var contador = 0;

        for(var i_contador = 0; i_contador < estatus.length; i_contador++){ 

          var parametros = {
            "id_estatus_ticket" : estatus[i_contador].id_ticket_estatus,
            "date_inicio" : date_inicio,
            "date_fin" : date_fin
          };

          getTicketsCantidadAjax(parametros, function(data) {    

              if (data.length > 0) {
                switch (data[0]['id_ticket_estatus']) {
                  case "1":
                    $("#span-asignados").html(data.length+" <small>Ticket(s)</small>");
                    break;
                  case "2":
                    $("#span-terminados").html(data.length+" <small>Ticket(s)</small>");
                    break;
                  case "3":
                    $("#span-activos").html(data.length+" <small>Ticket(s)</small>");
                    break;
                  case "4":
                    $("#span-cancelados").html(data.length+" <small>Ticket(s)</small>");
                    break;
                }
              }

              var valores = {"tipo":estatus[contador].nombre,"cantidad":data.length};
              arr_data.push(valores);
              contador++;

          });


        } //./termina for

        console.log(arr_data);

        // Aqui intento iterar al array de objetos pero no esta entrando

        for(var i = 0; i < arr_data.length; i++){
          alert("enttra");
        }

      }
```

> Datos que se encuentran adentro del array de objetos

```
[]
​
0: Object { tipo: "ASIGNADO", cantidad: 1 }
​
1: Object { tipo: "TERMINADO", cantidad: 0 }
​
2: Object { tipo: "ACTIVO", cantidad: 1 }
​
3: Object { tipo: "CANCELADO", cantidad: 1 }
​
length: 4
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Saludos para todos.

Comment: Qué error te aparece? El resultado del `console.log` es el que pones en la captura?

Comment: La captura de pantalla que muestro es el array de objetos, el mismo que quiero iterar. El for que coloque al final del codigo es para iterar el array de objetos, pero no esta entrando y se supone que si trae datos porque hice el console.log

Comment: le intente hacer como lo siguiente console.log(arr_data[0].tipo); y me manda error de Uncaught TypeError: arr_data[0] is undefined

Comment: Pasa lo mismo si intentas usar un `forEach`?

Comment: Quiero confirmar algo, así como está ese código te imprime en consola el resultado de `arr_data` antes de intentar iterar el arreglo o el contenido de `arr_data` se está imprimiendo desde otro lugar?